# How do I set a variable to a command's output in csh?

Tags: command-line, text-processing, csh

I have a number in a text file like :

```
int_width: 5230
```

I want to set this number (5230) to a variable in `csh`.
What is the correct form? (grep is working before setting)

```
set WIDTH = "$(grep int_width  *.txt | sed 's/[^0-9]*//g')"
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/218065/70524

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. In order to `set` variable in `csh` you need to use `set` ([more info](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/tcsh-csh-c_shell-set-variable-command/))
2. As mentioned by @muru comment - The original Bourne shell, `csh` or `tcsh` all do not support `$()` and require `` ` ` `` for command substitution.

Combine the above two and you'll get:

```
% set WIDTH=`grep int_width *.txt | sed "s,[^0-9]*,," `
% echo $WIDTH
5230
```